# Histogram of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]

I need to take histogram of each splited image and i want to calculate mean and variance of the splited image. here i am getting an error while i calculating the mean value..... please guide me

```
[h w c] = size(x);


numSplits = 3;  % 


sw = floor(w/numSplits);  % 


widths = repmat(sw, 1, numSplits-1);


widths(numSplits) = w - sum(widths); 


splits = mat2cell(x, h, widths, c);  



% show the splits


for ii=1:numSplits 


   subplot(1,numSplits,ii);


   imshow(splits{ii});

   g(ii)=(splits{ii});



   figure, imhist(g(ii));


end


%mean 

im1=g(ii);


su=mean2(im1);


mean=ceil(su);


disp('mean Value');



disp(mean)



%variance


 sv=double(im1);


 v = var(sv);


 disp(v)
```

i need to get the histograms of each seperate images and i need to calculate the mean for that splitted images

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume that `x` is the image you want to split and analyze and that it is the image you have linked:

First, I load the image (you have already done this, I guess, so you do not need to copy this):

```
x = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PAaI.png');
```

The following code solves your coding errors:

```
[h, w, c] = size(x);

numSplits = 3;  % 

sw = floor(w/numSplits);  % 
widths = repmat(sw, 1, numSplits-1);
widths(numSplits) = w - sum(widths); 
splits = mat2cell(x, h, widths, c);  

results = repmat(struct('mean',[], 'variance',[]),numSplits, 1);

% show and analyze the splits
for ii=1:numSplits 
    subplot(2,numSplits,ii);
    imshow(splits{ii});

    subplot(2,numSplits, ii+numSplits);
    imhist(splits{ii});

    results(ii).mean = mean2(splits{ii});
    results(ii).variance = (std2(splits{ii})).^2;
end
```

The mean and variance are stored in `results`:

```
>> results(1)

ans = 

  struct with fields:

        mean: 118.0233
    variance: 1.3693e+03

>> results(2)

ans = 

  struct with fields:

        mean: 126.1719
    variance: 1.9608e+03

>> results(3)

ans = 

  struct with fields:

        mean: 121.9004
    variance: 958.3740
```

However, please double check that you really want to compute the stats for the combined color channels of the images and not only for, for eample, the red one.